# Putting a hint on an android spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner, hint

I'm making a tiny application, and I have a spinner. Right now it shows the first option of the spinner as the text on the spinner when the application loads. I'd like it to show some special text like a hint when it loads the application. But when you press the spinner and get up the options, I would love for it to show the original options. Like right now it shows option number 0 when you load the application, but I want the text on it to say some other string.

Is this possible?

Comment: Trouble to explain what you want ?

Comment: Like written in the last part; "Like right now it shows option number 0 when you load the application, but I want the text on it to say some other string."

Comment: Are you asking, how to show string values in a spinner rather than the index value?

Comment: there's no `android:hint` attribute for Spinner (like there is for say, EditText) unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose now 0 is Selected But when App loading it set other String Which selection is in onItemSelected method

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        spinner.setSelection(2);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Hmm. That would actually work, but you would still be able to select the top selection. Is there any way you can disable an item in the spinner so that you can't select it?

Answer (score 3):

I handle this by using a button instead of a Spinner.   [I have the sample project up on GitHub.](https://github.com/sberg413/SpinnerButton)

In the project, i'm displaying both the Spinner and button to show that they indeed look identical.  Except the button you can set the initial text o whatever you want.

Here's what the activity looks like:

```
package com.stevebergamini.spinnerbutton;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Spinner spinner1;
    Button button1;
    AlertDialog ad;
    String[] countries;

    int selected = -1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country_names);

        //  You can also use an adapter for the allert dialog if you'd like
        //  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, countries);        

        ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setSingleChoiceItems(countries, selected,  
                new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            button1.setText(countries[which]);
                            selected = which;
                            ad.dismiss();

                        }}).setTitle(R.string.select_country).create(); 


        button1.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ad.getListView().setSelection(selected);
                ad.show();              
            }});

    }

}
```